# JAVA Stream API usage

Tags: java

I have a User entity

```
class User{
private String id; 
private String email;
private String name;
private int age :
... etc
}
```

I want to only retrieve some attributes of the User class and make a list of map.

How can I do this using Java 8 stream?

In other words I want to do this

```
Stream <User> s = List <User> users.stream();
// only retrive email and name attribute from user and make a map using JAVA 8 Stream
```

return type should be `List <Map <String, String>>` and look like below

```
{
 {
   "name" : "a",
   "email" : "aa@aa.com"
},
{
   "name" : "b",
   "email " : "bb@bb.com"

}
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of the output? To me it looks like a stream of Map<String, String>

Comment: Why do you want to make a list of maps? Making a class named `User` might be more suitable. Also, your data appears to be in JSON format and should be parsed.

Comment: output return type is List <Map<String,String>> i have some private data in User which should not be displayed so I used Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Stream.map()` like this:

```
List<Map<String,String>> result=users.stream().map(user->{
            Map<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
            map.put("name",user.getName());
            map.put("email",user.getEmail());
            return map;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Stream.map() can be used to map your stream object to anything you want.

Comment: if, by any chance you are on java 11 you can make it shorter:

    List<Map<String,String>> result=users.stream().collect(Collectors.mapping(e->Map.of("name", e.getName(), "email", e.getEmail()), Collectors.toList()));